# Stability analysis of ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

My questions concerns the stability analysis of the following dynamical system :

$\dfrac{d}{dt} a_{i}(t) = D_{i} + \displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{n}L_{ij}a_{j}(t) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} C_{ijk} a_{j}(t)a_{k}(t)}$

defined for the state variables $[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]^{T}$ with the real numbers
$D_i, L_{ij}, C_{ijk}$ for $i,j,k=1,...,n.$ The coefficients $C_{ijk}$ are assumed to be symmetric in $j$ and $k$ : $C_{ijk}=C_{ikj}$

What are the conditions for the asymptotically stability of this system ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is C matrix positive(negative) definite?

Comment: Let me know when you've solved this one - your equation incorporates the Lorenz system and many others, even just for $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an equilibrium solution $a^*$, the first thing to look at is the linear stability.  Generically, the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix of the right side at $a^*$ will tell you this (the exceptions being when there are eigenvalues with real part $0$ and any others are all in the left half plane).